# How do I check if the text under the cursor in a contenteditable div is "bold"

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Identify whether the selected text in a web page is bold nor not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404618/identify-whether-the-selected-text-in-a-web-page-is-bold-nor-not)

I've created a contenteditable div, and this was straightforward enough.

I have as well added a control on top of the div to bold and unbold the text.

Now, I would like to style the button based on the bold status of the text under the cursor - ie: if the text under the cursor is bold, I would like the bold icon to have border 'inset'... and if it's not bold, I would like the bold icon to be without a border.

How can I check the style of the element under the cursor?

Link to the code as it is now:
http://jsfiddle.net/aCp7M/

Comment: it would be useful to show us your code

Comment: some progress with this?

Comment: I have added in a link to my code. I would like the icon "B" to show with a border when the text under the cursor is bold.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/vvCzD/

Use `document.queryCommandValue("Bold")` to check that text at the caret position is bold and so on.
All possible command identifiers are described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

---

**UPD:**
As Tim stated below, a correct method for getting boolean-like properties is `queryCommandState`.

Comment: I believe `document.queryCommandState("Bold")` is the correct method for bold. `queryCommandValue()` is used for commands that have a value (such as "fontName") rather than just toggling.

Comment: Here's an updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vvCzD/1/

Comment: @TimDown, thanks for the hint. You are completely right.