# How to get formatted text if selection is inside tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, formatting, selection

If I select (highlight with mouse) bold text, I want to have <b></b> tags around it (the same goes for <i>, <span style="color:red">, <sup>, etc...).
The problem appears when You starting to select bold words inside all-bold sentence. Logically if I selected bold text - I want to copy bold text to other place. But if selection doesn't cross formatting tags I loose format info...
Here is working fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/xt557ov5/1/

1. Select **just** word BOLD in first line & press button.
2. Now select **all** second line, and press a button.

If you want even more magic - select just word LINE, exactly from first letter to the last (four letters no spaces around) - You also will get LINE without any bold formatting around it.

Snippet :

```js
$('#extract').on('click', function() {
  extract();
});

function extract() {
  var str = getSelectionHtml();
  str = str.toString().replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
  console.log(str);
  $('#result').empty().append(str);
}

function getSelectionHtml() {
  var html = "";
  if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
      var container = document.createElement("div");
      for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
        container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
      }
      html = container.innerHTML;
    }
  } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
    if (document.selection.type == "Text") {
      html = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
    }
  }
  return html;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="extract">Extract</button>
<br>
<br>
<div id="edit">
  <br>
  <b>Select here just word BOLD and press [Extract].</b>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>Now select all this <b>LINE</b>, and press [Extract].
</div>
<h4>Result:</h4>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would help: [stackoverflow: Identify wether the selected text in a web page is bold or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404618/identify-whether-the-selected-text-in-a-web-page-is-bold-nor-not)

In order to apply it to your code I constructed this:

```
...

function selectionIsBold() {
        var range, isBold = false;
        if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
            if (sel && sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            document.designMode = "on";
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
            }
        }
        if (document.queryCommandState) {
            isBold = document.queryCommandState("bold");
        }
        if (document.designMode == "on") {
        document.designMode = "off";
        }
        return isBold;
    }
function extract(){
        var str = getSelectionHtml();
        if(selectionIsBold()){
            str= "&lt;b&gt;"+str.toString()+"&lt;/b&gt;";
        }else{

            str = str.toString().replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");   
        }
        $('#result').empty().append(str);
    }
...
```

Note: selectionIsBold returns also true when thr text is "<strong>"-tagged. For other text formation checks (e.g <i>) change

```
isBold = document.queryCommandState("bold");
```

to

```
isBold = document.queryCommandState("italic");
```

Comment: Thanks Eierschale, that helped me a lot. I will have to add check for color with command `document.queryCommandValue('foreColor')` and other properties. 
Also many strange things is happening (maybe because of not final support of those commands). I.e. if you select heading text `document.queryCommandState("heading")` will always return false, but `document.queryCommandValue("heading")` will return string `"h2"`, or empty `""` if selected text is really not a header.
Here is a list of available properties https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Commands

Comment: `document.queryCommandValue("heading")` - Chrome returns empty string (when actually selected text is inside <h2> ), Mozilla returns `"h2"`, and IE gives `"Invalid argument."` error.

Comment: For Chrome you can get the format tag (h1, h2, ..., p, ...) from `document.queryCommandValue("formatBlock")`